# How to get ID of the Last Inserted Record in SQL using ASP.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server

Here is my code

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["id"]))
    {
        string clientId = Context.User.Identity.GetUserId();

        if (clientId != null)
        {

            int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
            customize1 customize = new customize1
            {
                client_id = clientId,
                product_id = id,
                paper_type = Labelpt.Text,
                corner = Labelpc.Text,
                shipping_type = Labelsp.Text,
                text = TextBox3.Text,

                amount = Convert.ToInt32(lbResult.Text)

            };
            customizeModel model = new customizeModel();
            Label9.Text = model.Insertcustomize(customize);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd2 = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd2.CommandText = "select top 1 * from customize1 where client_id='"+clientId+"' order by Id desc ";
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
            da2.Fill(dt2);
            foreach (DataRow dr2 in dt2.Rows)
            {
                customizeid = dr2["Id"].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I need the last row id but my query does not generate any value.I also check my query in SSMS and query is working fine but in asp it is not generating any data and for inserting record i used the concept of class and entity relationship.
Any Solution.

Comment: Your code isn't *inserting* anything into the database, what ID are you looking for?

Comment: I updated my full query, please check.

Comment: You're still not inserting anything into the database.  Getting a generated ID involves *inserting a record* to generate that ID.  It's really not clear what you're trying to do or what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Brother there are two ways:

One is when you insert your row place after the Insert query this:

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

For example:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
        VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...); 
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

It gives the inserted ID back.

The second way is this query;

```
SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

If you keep struggling with problems be open to ask more.

Comment: It's worth noting that your second approach, if not part of the same atomic operation, could very easily return the wrong identifier due to race conditions.